# django in production generates cahe page everytime opening url

Tags: python, django, caching, wagtail

I have a site on django. It generate cahe page each time for I open it. I can't find out the reason. Here is wsgi application + ngix. This is not personal server, I asked support ofcause, but I want to know what the reason is! 
I thought about html5min, but without cashe doesn't load< but generates new pages in it.
Production is python 2.7 + Django last + Wagtail last

In test mode when djangos server is alone, the cache works correct.
On test is is python 3 + Django last + Wagtail last

Annother question is: does wsgi application every time runs django? Or it needs to run it manualy? If so, how to look if it runs on hosting?
Please help me!

I got now cache is ok. But problem is still here. Request is running with cached keys in 1362 ms, but I want it to run not more 200 ms, What the problem maybe in here?

```
MIDDLEWARE = [ 
# 'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
# 'django.middleware.cache.CacheMiddleware',
# 'htmlmin.middleware.HtmlMinifyMiddleware',
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
'wagtail.wagtailcore.middleware.SiteMiddleware',
'wagtail.wagtailredirects.middleware.RedirectMiddleware',
# other middleware classes
# 'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',
# 'htmlmin.middleware.MarkRequestMiddleware',

]
```

Comment: Support answered - django doesnt run as daemon... what caching can be in ths project?

Comment: Django has a built in caching framework. Are you using it? Check your settings file(s) for `CACHES`. In development, many set this to be `DummyCache` so that nothing gets cached. Do you have `@cache` decorators on any of your views, or `{% cache %}` tags in your templates? What WSGI server are you using with `nginx`?

Comment: Yes ofcause I use it. I found a problem  - it was in adding cahe middleware without any get or post params. But it doesnt match to me. Now I try to do memcached cache with template tags.  \n Now its a new situation, Django gets the request< puts in into cashe< but it seems< it doesnt get from there, jow can I check it?

Comment: Can you include the template cache tag you're using in your question, as well as your relevant settings?

Comment: I got it, cashe is good. But problem is still here. Here is screen http://f3.s.qip.ru/veBVkrhw.png   Where is time for request is going out I can't find